# How to estimate the learning time of ML algorithms?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist, google-colaboratory

This code has been running for over 2 hours and I don't know if it's stuck or running, so how to estimate the learning time of code involving ML algorithms? I am using Google Colaboratory,  with no GPU and Python 3.

[image]
<sup>**Python notebook**</sup>

Comment: if you add verbose=True to GridSearchCV, it will show you time notifications. However, the task of predicting the time that program is running, is impossible. However, you should understand algorithm complexity to roughly know how much time it will work.

Answer (score 0):

When using `GridSearchCV` you can specify the verbosity parameter `verbose`. See [API docu](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for more details. It's default is 0 which implies that you get no messages, however, increasing the integer will result in more detailed messages about what folds and parameters are being currently fitted and what are the elapsed times.